# Machine becomes totally unresponsive whilst modifying files via samba

Tags: samba

Apologies for cross-posting this from the ubuntu forums, but it feels like questions often go completely unanswered there.

I've had this problem a few times now, and it's really worrying me, as it means I have to hard reset. Normally Ubuntu is so stable!

I have samba set up on an Ubuntu server (11.04), sharing a directory mounted on a RAID 5 array managed by mdadm. If I access this via a Windows PC, and modify a large number of files quickly (e.g. some bulk edit operation, in this case applying changes to tags of music files), the server becomes completely unresponsive.

By that I mean the connection is lost, I can't SSH into or ping it, and pressing keys on the keyboard does nothing (which I can see if I log on locally first; after the lock up the terminal doesn't respond at all).

I left it for about an hour last time this happened and it didn't get any better, so I had to hard reset it, which I *really* don't want to do again. Also, just waiting isn't really a good solution, I'd expect it to always be responsive.

This has happened 3 or 4 times now, and seems completely repeatable - I get around it by modifying smaller batches of files. That said, it happened just now after copying about 10MB to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a lot of issues running anything on 11.04. The latest version introduces a lot of overhead. I've found that running 10.04 LTS is much more stable. I'm currently running a Samba file server on Ubuntu Server 10.04 and it runs like a dream.